# HTML focus and blur when input checkbox label clicked

Tags: focus, blur

I have an HTML label and HTML input checkbox and I need a stream of *focus* and *blur* events that behaves correctly when I click on the label.

(In real app there is a Bootstrap component that hides the input because of styling - so the interaction is not with the checkbox itself but with label styled as checkbox (checkbox itself is invisible, opacity=0).)

The problem is that when I click the label then the real checkbox loses focus (1) (if it previously had focus) and after that it gains the focus again (2). So it generates couple of events blur and focus. I need to get rid of them. This happens only for clicking on the label.

I do not understand why this happens because label should not be focusable.

Example:

```html
  <label for="checkbox">Click On CheckBox Label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

```js
import { of, map, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const element = document.querySelector('#checkbox');

fromEvent(element, 'focus').subscribe((event) => console.log('focus'));
fromEvent(element, 'blur').subscribe((event) => console.log('blur'));
```

Click on label generates two events:

First Click on label:

- `blur`  // the label gains focus ?
- `focus` // checkbox re-gains focus

Second Click on label:

- `blur`  // the label gains focus ?
- `focus` // checkbox re-gains focus

...

I would like to get a RxJS stream of focus and blur as if clicked on real checkbox.

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4zryhd?file=index.ts) demo.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not linked to rxjs but basic JS events. `blur` is trigered on `mousedown`.

Just `preventDefault` on that event to prevent the label from stealing the focus !

```
fromEvent(label, 'mousedown').subscribe((event) => event.preventDefault());
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hw54rd?file=index.ts)

Comment: You are right, that will prevent the focus switching but also prevents the checkbox to be checked / unchecked (when clicking on the label) :) . I need to keep this behavior because the checkbox in real the application is hidden (due to styling).

Comment: @Felix No, It won't break it !  Please see my exampel !

Comment: Doh, my bad. I have tried `preventDefault()` for **click** instead of **mousedown** ‍♂️ . It works. Thanks 

Comment: One more complementary question: Is the solution somewhere documented (MDN)? Or is it experimental test, or how do you now such a subtle thing? 

Comment: Yeah It's a bit a experimental testing and some background knownledge on how event work ! (and how to prevent them =) )

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for a solution to my problem for 3 hours.
I have several labels pointing to the same input. The input has a transition that runs on focus. And that transition was being triggered EVERY time the labels were clicked even though the input already had focus.
Your description of the issue was spot-on.